# Скачать картинку с сайта, не имея к ней доступа (Cloudflare, access denied)

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

На сайте есть картинки. Не могу скачать их обычным способом. Если перейти по ссылке на картинку, доступ запрещён Cloudflare, то есть, доступ к картинке есть только у сайта.

Способы, которые я нашёл:

1. Сделать "скриншот узла", через просмотр кода.
2. Создать элемент `<a></a>`, в котором указать ссылку на картинку, и добавить атрибут download.

Но такие способы не подходят, так как это нужно делать вручную. А мне нужно, в идеале, передавать ссылки на картинки на мой сервер, и там уже, каким-то образом, скачивать их.

Есть идеи? Может, кто-то сталкивался с подобным.

Comment: Пробуйте через селенимум

Comment: Есть вариант с `Puppeteer`, через него запускать страницу и оттуда стягивать нужные изображения. Но это крайний случай. Если найдутся другие варианты, то лучше воспользоваться ими